# Bracketing number for monotone functions $f:\mathbb{R} \to [0,1]$.

Tags: probability-theory, entropy, empirical-processes

I have been trying to understand a bound on the log of the bracketing number for monotone functions with range in $[0,1]$. My book claims that constructing the brackets as piecewise constant functions on a regular grid will bring about a bound of order $1/\epsilon \log(1/\epsilon)$ but I do not see how one can arrive at this. If someone has an idea, could I please enlist their help?

The $\epsilon$-bracketing number is defined as the minimum number of brackets of size at most $\epsilon$ needed to cover a given set of functions. A set of functions $\mathcal{F}$ is covered by $\epsilon$-brackets $[l_j, u_j], j=1, \ldots, N$ if  $\mathcal{F} \subset \cup_j [l_j, u_j]$ and $u_j(x)-l_j(x) < \epsilon$. This minimum number of brackets is closely related to entropy, which is defined as the logarithm of that number and is crucial in the theory of empirical processes.

Comment: What does "cover" mean in this context?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Please see my edit.

Comment: What does it mean for a set of functions to be contained in a union of intervals? Does it mean the union of the ranges of the functions is contained in the union of the set of intervals?

Comment: @GerryMyerson $l_j$ and $u_j$ denote functions, not real numbers. In effect this means that for each $f \in \mathcal{F}$ that is in one of the brackets $[l_j, u_j]$ we must have $l_j(x) \leq f(x) \leq u_j(x)$.

Comment: The bracketing number for the set of monotone functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,1]$ is infinite. To see this consider the following sequence of functions:

$f_n(x)=\cases{0 \text{ for } x<n \\ 1 \text{ for } x \ge n}$

Each of the $f_n$ will require a separate bracket.

Comment: @AngelaRichardson That cannot be true, otherwise you break down the whole theory of empirical processes.

Comment: Can you mention what book you're using?

Comment: @AngelaPretorius You misuderstood the concept of bracketing number. Take the space of your functions:

$$ \mathfrak{F}:= \{ f_n (x) = \mathbb{1}_{[n,\infty)}(x) \: : \: n \in \mathbb{N} \}$$

Set $\delta = 1$, then the bracketing number of $\mathfrak{F}$ with such $\delta$ is just 1 because $\sup_{x} |\mathbb{1}_{[n,\infty)}(x) - \mathbb{1}_{[k,\infty)}(x)| = 1$. So you can take as upper bracket just the function constantly 1 and as lower bracket the functions constantly 0. The distance between the upper bracket and the lower bracket is exactly $\delta$ in the sup norm.

Comment: @mlstudent The book: Weak convergence and Empirical Processes by van der Vaart and Wellner